# How am I meant to use sort?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

In Haskell Turtle, sort has the type `(Functor io, MonadIO io, Ord a) => Shell a -> io [a]`. It takes a stream in the form of a Shell monad, sorts it into a list, but then wraps it in a `MonadIO`???

This seems counter-intuitive to me. My beginner eyes say that a `MonadIO` should only be used when interacting with the outside world, which `sort` doesn't need to do.

I would have expected `sort` to be `(Ord a) => Shell a -> Shell a` so it fits into a stream nicely.

Is this an oversight by the package authors, or am I not understanding how `sort` should be used?

Comment: My guess is `IO [a]` (or any MonadIO) is weaker than `Shell a` because the latter has side-effects for each elements, whereas in a sorted list all side-effects associated with the input list have been already executed. You can always embed a list into a shell if you want.

Comment: `Shell` is an instance of `Functor` and `MonadIO` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.25/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#t:Shell), so you can think the type of `sort` is `Order a => Shell a -> Shell [a]` if you want. It's just that `sort` is more generic than that.

Answer (score 3):

`MonadIO io => io [a]` is better than `Shell a`, because `Shell` is a `MonadIO` instance and `select` lifts lists to `Shell`s. So, if you want, you can write your own more specific `sort` that has the type you like, implemented with the `sort` provided by turtle:

```
sortStream :: Ord a => Shell a -> Shell a
sortStream = sort >=> select
```

Comment: This answer does not explain why similar utilities (like nub or uniq) use `Shell a` result type rather than `MonadIO io => io [a]`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I don't know why for sure, but my guess would be that those utilities cannot have the better type and retain their behavior. The Unix `uniq` can stream its results, and perhaps turtle's `uniq` can too; whereas a thing of type `MonadIO io => io [a]` cannot. (It is in general the case that more polymorphic types cannot behave in as many ways as more monomorphic types -- a fact we exploit often when reasoning about Haskell programs.)